# Word to describe someone who is ignorant of societal problems

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that describes someone who advocates for harmful laws or policies; it would describe someone who writes policy without listening to the people it affects or someone who doesn't pay attention to actual effects of that policy, kind of like politically or socially tone-deaf. They might continue to stand behind that policy even after it was proven to be ineffective or harmful.

It would be like ignorant or deluded, but specifically regarding knowledge of people's situations or societal problems and solutions.
A word to describe the actions of that person would be helpful as well.
As an example:

> It was very __ of the senator to vote for the harmful bill that would require every homeless person to own a car.

The word wouldn't refer to someone doing this knowingly and maliciously, but I would like it to have a negative connotation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

> ***[out of touch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20touch)*** -  in a state of not knowing what is happening, how certain people feel, etc.

Honestly I struggled thinking of a term for this, but struck on googling the "[It's one banana, what could it cost? $10?](https://melmagazine.com/en-us/story/the-inside-story-of-the-10-banana-on-arrested-development)" moment.

Specifically, I think of this as out of touch with *reality*, which is why synonyms like *detached* don't quite have the same meaning.

Comment: In France we have several examples of quotes very similar to this $10 banana moment... Except those are not from TV shows, but from actual real-life politicians in live interviews. The [minister for public transportation](https://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Nathalie_Kosciusko-Morizet) got the price of a subway ticket wrong by a factor of 3; and [the government's spokesperson](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Cop%C3%A9) got the price of a chocolat croissant wrong by a factor of 10.

Comment: I think *detached* is the best answer so far.

Comment: Ignorantly out of touch is the best phrase response so far.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - *Reality-detached* maybe, and attachment may go back to similar roots as *in touch*.  Probably why both came to mind.   But I think of *detached* by itself as not being emotionally involved; detached from others' feelings-- not from reality.  More connotation that the others are specific people, not the entire nation.  Close though.

Answer (score 14):

merriam-webster.com

*Tone-deaf*

1: relatively insensitive to differences in musical pitch

2: having or showing an obtuse insensitivity or lack of perception particularly in matters of public sentiment, opinion, or taste

- The White House long ago concluded that she is aloof and politically tone-deaf …—Michael Duffy
- At the time, I wondered how such an intelligent man could be so
  tone-deaf to the harsh realities facing the nation …— Peniel E.
  Joseph

Answer (score 7):

**Myopic**, As defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myopic)

> 2
> : lacking in foresight or discernment : narrow in perspective and without concern for broader implications

Also by [The Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/myopic)

> 2 : **disapproving** : only thinking or caring about things that are happening now or that relate to a particular group rather than things that are in the future or that relate to many people
>
> - myopic politicians
> - He has criticized the government's myopic [=shortsighted] diplomatic policies.
> - a myopic view of the world

An example used here in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jun/15/crumbling-remain-vote-hollowed-out-labour) (2016):

> This is where it was presumed anti-globalisation protest was located. The left could interact with this element. It recognised it. Now? It is tone deaf and increasingly myopic.

Can also be modified for flavor with words like *stubbornly*, *selfishly*, or *harmfully*.

Answer (score 4):

A person who does not take in the whole picture is **blinkered**:

> *blinkered* [adjective]:
>
> A blinkered person is unable or unwilling to understand other people's
> beliefs, and blinkered opinions or ways of behaving show someone is
> unable or unwilling to understand other people:
>
> - *He's very blinkered in his outlook*. ...
> - *It has to be, so that its lessons and recommendations sink in to the dim or blinkered consciousness of politicians with the authority
>   to make a material response.*
> - *He has not been constricted by the language of the civil service and has not taken a narrow and blinkered view.* [Hansard]

Someone who consistently refuses to listen to reasonable attempts to get them to change their mind is **hidebound**.

Comment: Good, but it lacks impact and effectiveness. Nobody is going to know what I mean if I say "It was very blinkered of the senator to vote for ...". Nobody is going to know what I mean. Tone deaf feels more intuitively understandable.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal They aren't synonyms though.  Consider the quote below, "It is tone deaf _and_ increasingly myopic". Myopic and blinkered are more synonyms.  I think blinkered suggests, the senator doesn't perceive the information or, maybe, chooses not to accept it; tone deaf means, they could perceive it, but didn't understand the implications.  (In OP example, the information being, homeless people are generally very poor.)

Answer (score 3):

You may consider ***thoughtless*** or its synonyms like *inconsiderate, uncaring, unmindful & insensitive*.

> It was very ***thoughtless*** of the senator to vote for the harmful
> bill that would require every homeless person to own a car.

Google dictionary:

> **[thoughtless](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20thoughtless)**
> *adjective*
>
> 1. (of a person or their behaviour) not showing consideration for the needs of other people.
>    "it was thoughtless of her to have rushed
>    out and not said where she would be going"
> 2. without consideration of the possible consequences.
>    "to think a few minutes of thoughtless pleasure could end in this"

Answer (score 3):

Someone who just doesn't understand either the situation or the possible impact of their proposal could just be [**oblivious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious):

> lacking active conscious knowledge or awareness

If the senator is simply ignorant of things in general, they might be oblivious.  Or, they could know some things (like the politics of getting a law passed) but be ignorant of life outside their sphere - if they were competent within their own realm but simply had no operational knowledge relevant to the actual effects of the law they might be **[siloed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/siloed)**:

> kept in isolation in a way that hinders communication and cooperation

Other words would be more specific as to *why* the senator is ignorant.  Are they perhaps highly-educated, and concerned with only theoretical concerns rather than practical effects?  Then they might be **[ivory tower](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ivory%20tower)** or simply **[impractically](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impractical)** idealistic:

> a secluded place that affords the means of treating practical issues with an impractical often escapist attitude.  Especially: a place of learning

Or are they unaware of the concerns of unhoused people because they consider themselves socially better?  If so, the senator might be **[aloof](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aloof)**:

> removed or distant either physically or emotionally

Or because they are wealthy?  They might be **[plutocratic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/plutocratic):**

> powerful because of being rich

Or, if the senator is unconcerned about the effects of the law on the plebeians because he is both wealthy *and* of high social class, he could be **[patrician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patrician):**

> a person of high birth : ARISTOCRAT, a person of breeding and cultivation

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **Callous**

> 2 Callous
>
> > a: feeling no emotion
> >
> > b: feeling or showing no sympathy for others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callous

Comment: I was thinking "callously indifferent" or "callous indifference".

Comment: Callous is good.

Comment: The question is about people who are unaware of the likely results of policies. To me, *callous* suggests someone who is aware that the policies will cause great suffering, but doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call someone like this a "troglodyte". A person who is a troglodyte, could be described as "troglodytic".

This means "a stupid person who has old-fashioned views or habits, or behaves in a way that is not considered socially acceptable" [[1]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/troglodyte).

The example given in the cited definition is actually in the context of politics too: "He urged the minister not to be slowed down in any way by the reactionary troglodyte forces in all parties who opposed reform."

Comment: I'll add that "dinosaur" is another option with essentially the same connotation, although it doesn't fit particularly well in the example sentence as an adjective - it would be more commonly used as a noun and might require a little more context to be readily understood.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - Dinosauric is the adjective you're looking for I do believe

Answer (score 0):

If it's an adjective you're looking for, perhaps try [self-serving](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-serving):

> Serving one's own interests often in disregard of the truth or the interests of others.

Comment: This doesn't have the 'ignorant' bit of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: There's only so much one word or phrase can do. Two or more are probably needed to convey everything intended, like "self-serving, blinkered, and uninformed …"

Comment: @Heartspring If the person in question is remaining ignorant because it's comfortable, I'd say "self-serving" is at least part of the description.

Comment: Could he not be "ignorant _and_ self serving"? self-serving does not preclude ignorance, but specifically describes them being focused on their own agenda.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller — Certainly. Although one could argue it's inherently ignorant to be self-serving … although that pretty much means we're all ignorant. :p

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, English judges have required to be brought up to date with real life when everyday trivialities are mentioned in Court.

'Eastenders is a popular soap opera on television, m'Lud.'

But I cannot think of a single word that conveys such ***cloistered un-involvement.***

Answer (score -3):

I would change the sentence a little by adding an extra adverb, like this:

> The Senator came off as **pharisaic** when he voted **self-righteously** for the
> bill that would require every homeless person to own a car.

**pharisaic:**

(lowercase) practicing or advocating strict observance of external forms and ceremonies of religion or conduct without regard to the spirit; hypocritical.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pharisaic

**self-righteous:**

confident of one's own righteousness, especially when smugly moralistic and intolerant of the opinions and behavior of others.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-righteous

Answer (score -7):

**disingenuous**
adjective

> **lacking in candor**
> also : **giving a false appearance of simple
> frankness : CALCULATING**

disingenuously adverb

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)

But the guy might be outright malicious.

Comment: Disingenuous generally means they're lying, not making a mistake due to ignorance.

Comment: @Barmar my friend, I know that. But it seem her description depicts some duplicitous and deceitful. Maybe she's needs a push for something stronger? :) Deluded, she said.

Comment: I think the author of the bill might be duplicitous and deceitful. But the senator in this sentence has apparently been duped and is just going along because he doesn't realize how harmful it is. At least, that's how I interpret the OP.

Comment: @Barmar There is only the senator in that question.

Comment: The question mentions a bill. That bill had to have been written by someone. They're not the same as the senator voting for it.

Comment: @Barmar In my opinion, the OP is missing the boat.

Comment: I think they're givintg the politician the benefit of the doubt. But I've heard many politicians express truly ignorant beliefs. Like the one who thought that rape victims would naturally abort (so we don't need exclusions in anti-abortion laws), or ones who have no idea how much a gallon of milk costs. "The Internet is a series of tubes."

Comment: Regardless, I didn't deserve two down votes.

Comment: And I'm not one of the downvoters. If my comments prompted them to DV, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm giving an upvote to offset one of the drive-by DVs. If you're reading this and want to downvote this answer, leave a comment, hey?

Comment: @Conrado Thanks.

Comment: @Conrado +1 for drive-by DVs. :)